# how to programatically remove windows service in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I have a service's name and I want to stop and remove this windows service, how to do it?
I searched DeleteService but I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Was [the MSDN "Deleting a Service" example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682571(v=vs.85).aspx) unhelpful?

Comment: thanks! this example is helpful but i didn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least if memory serves, the sequence is something close to this:

1. OpenSCManager
2. OpenService
3. ControlService(service, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ...
4. DeleteService
5. CloseServiceHandle(service)
6. CloseServiceHandle(manager)

See the [Deleting a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example on MSDN.

Comment: Also CloseServiceHandle(service).

Comment: @SergeyPodobry: Oops, quite right (it won't be deleted until the handle is closed).

Comment: And ControlService is truly necessary. the DeleteService doc said if the service is running it will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have defined the following:

```
#define SERVICE_NAME            _T("myservice")             // Service name
```

and

```
SERVICE_STATUS          serviceStatus;
```

The code would be:

```
void WINAPI UninstallService(void) 
{

    SC_HANDLE hSCManager = NULL;
    SC_HANDLE hService = NULL;

    hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
    if (!hSCManager) 
    {
        wprintf(L"Open Service Manager failed\n");
        return;
    }

    hService = OpenService(hSCManager, SERVICE_NAME, DELETE | SERVICE_STOP);
    if (hService == NULL) 
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        wprintf(L"Open service failed\n");
        return;
    }


    // Deleting the service
    if (!DeleteService(hService)) 
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        wprintf(L"Delete service failed\n");
        return;
    }
    wprintf(L"Service deleted\n");

    // Stopping the service  
    serviceStatus = { 0 };
    ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP,(LPSERVICE_STATUS)&serviceStatus);

    CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);

}
```